# RunTime Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable "tab" was corrupted

Tags: c

I'm training in C language and I'm doing an program that create a simple array and sort him.
Here's the code :

**Main.c :**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, int *argv[])
{
    int tab[5]={2,5,3,9,4}, i=0, longueur=0;

    /*for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        tab[i] = i;
    }*/

    longueur = sizeof(tab)/sizeof(tab[0]);
    trierTab(tab,longueur);
    afficherTab(tab,longueur);
    return 0;
```

**Tableaux.c :**

```
#include "tableaux.h"

//Sort the array
void trierTab(int tab[],int longueur)
{
    int i=0, j=0,max=0,indiceMax=0,temp=0;

    for(i=longueur-1; i>=1;i--)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
        {
            if(tab[j]>max)
            {
                max = tab[j];
                indiceMax = j;
            }
        }

        temp=tab[j];
        tab[j]=max;
        tab[indiceMax]=temp;
    }
}



//Print the array
void afficherTab(int tab[], int longueur)
{
    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<longueur;i++)
    {
        printf("| %d |",tab[i]);
    }
}
```

I guess that there is an out of bound error, but I can't figure out where she is :s
Can someone help me please ? ^^

Comment: After the loop `for(j=0;j<=i;j++)` has finished `j` will have a value of `i+1` which you then use for `tab[j]=max`. But `i` started as `i=longueur-1` so `j` can be `longueur` which is beyond the array bounds.

Comment: Omfg, I'm stupid x)
Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you exit from this for loop the first time:

```
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
    {
        if(tab[j]>max)
        {
            max = tab[j];
            indiceMax = j;
        }
    }
```

The value of `j` is `5`.

Then you assign:

```
temp=tab[j];
```

So you are reading out of the bounds of `tab` (`temp=tab[5];`)